# Titanium - Mapview and annotations

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, titanium, android-mapview, appcelerator

I am an iPhone developer and a beginner in Titanium Studio. I have some ideas about basic concepts of using view, window, tabBar in Titanium. I need to proceed advance to deal with MapViews. Where can I find some guidelines or some samples to work with GeoLocations, open a mapView, get the current location, get latitude and longitudes, point annotation on the specified location. I have another basic question and it will be very silly as I started learning Titanium yesterday. How can I print a string as I use 'NSLog' and 'printf'? Answers are welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print in console you can use,

```
Ti.API.info("String to Print");
Ti.API.debug("String to Print");
Ti.API.error("String to Print");
Ti.API.warn("String to Print");
```

Check that Geolocation and Map API ([Links already provided by Muhammad Zeeshan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8341563/253169)) and try to implement a sample code. If find any difficulties than you can post to community again.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

In order to find the details of the objects you want to use, you need to go to the details of

- [Titanium.Geolocation](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Geolocation-module)
- [Titanium.Map](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Map-module)

If you want to display the string on the screen you can use

- [Titanium.UI.Label](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.Label-object)

There is a very good code example you can use [Seven days with Titanium](http://cssgallery.info/seven-days-with-titanium-day-5-gps-and-maps/)